# $_get not working to get data from a newly created URL by js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a program where I will need to change a URL when I open a modal.

```
window.history.pushState('', 'Admin Account','admin-account.php?Name=' + strName);
```

When I click the submit button, I need to get the "Name" variable that is in the URL.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){
    if(isset($_GET['Name'])){
        $old = $_GET['Name'];
        echo 'Name = '.$old;
    }
    else{
       echo 'not successful'; //This is what I always get. I can't get the value
    }
}
else{ 
  echo 'not clicked'; //when the button Update isn't clicked
}
?>
```

The other code that are related to this process is in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mnkefzxr/1/). I have also placed a snippet of php there so it won't work, but I just compiled the related snippets there.

Comment: Do you understand that php code is not processed by jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes. I just figured to put it there so the codes here won't be a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the wrong thing as far as the form is concerned: You need to add the parameter to the `action` attribute of the form to make sure it gets sent with the form.

So something like (untested, but I think the idea is clear):

```
window.history.pushState('', 'Admin Account','admin-account.php?Name=' + strName);
// Add it to the form action attribute as well
$('form').attr('action', $('form').attr('action') + '?Name=' + strName);
```

Note that you would need to parse and rebuild the query parameter string if there are more parameters concerned or the code in question can be run multiple times.

Comment: *"So something like (untested, but I think the idea is clear)"* - that's where we separate the men from the boys; you're "that" good ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm honoured. Slow Saturday? :-)

Comment: @jeroen As it should ;-) not much of a "working day" *per se*.